# How to archive specific tabs from a sheet into one sheet in a Drive Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

long time lurker and learner. First question...

I have a script running on a Sheet that has multiple tabs, I have figured out how to export the tabs I need, albeit in a clunky way but it works. The idea being the user would archive off these tabs at the end of each week.

My issue is, and I'm almost certain this is a simple thing....currently it exports each tab into its own new sheet, names it by date/time and the name of the tab, ideally I'd like it to basically combine those tabs into a new sheet.

I'm assuming that's possible just been round the houses trying to work it out!

This is my current script which works, but after several weeks I end up tons and tons of sheets as I'm exporting 7 tabs a time. I'm one of those boomers who learnt to code back in the 80s/early 90s in stuff like Cobol and RPG and so I've cobbled this together really from a lot of back and forth!

Equally - I have no idea to get it to save as a sheet as a google sheet doesn't have a file extension (Google) hence why its currently saving as XLSX which isn't ideal as we're all Google based!

````
function CycleXLSX(){
ExportSheetAsXLSX()
ExportSheetAsXLSX2()
ExportSheetAsXLSX3()
ExportSheetAsXLSX4()
ExportSheetAsXLSX5()
ExportSheetAsXLSX6()
ExportSheetAsXLSX7()
}


function getFileAsBlob(exportUrl) {
 let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
     muteHttpExceptions: true,
     headers: {
       Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
     },
   });
 return response.getBlob();
}

function ExportSheetAsXLSX() {
 var Savedfilename
 Savedfilename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Camden Timesheet').getRange(5,3).getValue() + " - Main Camden Timesheet"
 let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID OF TAB 1]/export?format=xlsx&gid=785875940");
 blob.setName(Savedfilename)
 //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER]');
 let file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 //let file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
}

function ExportSheetAsXLSX2() {
 var Savedfilename
 Savedfilename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Camden Timesheet').getRange(5,3).getValue() + " - BRERCY Timesheet"
 let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID OF TAB 2]/export?format=xlsx&gid=1465650872");
 blob.setName(Savedfilename)
 //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER]');
 let file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 //let file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
}

function ExportSheetAsXLSX3() {
 var Savedfilename
 Savedfilename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Camden Timesheet').getRange(5,3).getValue() + " - BP Timesheet"
 let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID OF TAB 3]/export?format=xlsx&gid=584316904");
 blob.setName(Savedfilename)
 //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER]');
 let file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 //let file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
}

function ExportSheetAsXLSX4() {
 var Savedfilename
 Savedfilename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Camden Timesheet').getRange(5,3).getValue() + " - CTW Timesheet"
 let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID OF TAB 4]/export?format=xlsx&gid=1441749747");
 blob.setName(Savedfilename)
 //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER]');
 let file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 //let file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
}

function ExportSheetAsXLSX5() {
 var Savedfilename
 Savedfilename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Camden Timesheet').getRange(5,3).getValue() + " - CUE Timesheet"
 let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID OF TAB 5]/export?format=xlsx&gid=2120066067");
 blob.setName(Savedfilename)
 //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER]');
 let file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 //let file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
}

function ExportSheetAsXLSX6() {
 var Savedfilename
 Savedfilename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Camden Timesheet').getRange(5,3).getValue() + " - DD Timesheet"
 let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID OF TAB 6]/export?format=xlsx&gid=1063749958");
 blob.setName(Savedfilename)
 //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER]');
 let file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 //let file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
}

function ExportSheetAsXLSX7() {
 var Savedfilename
 Savedfilename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Camden Timesheet').getRange(5,3).getValue() + " - USG Timesheet"
 let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID OF TAB 7]/export?format=xlsx&gid=1211788971");
 blob.setName(Savedfilename)
 //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER]');
 let file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 //let file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what Spreadsheet you wish to access so here's an example of how to archive three sheets to the first sheet of another spreadsheet

```
function archiveSheets(id = "1Y2mT5ahv2GYcnmAw8UyRbuCUDVmPDTXw8qtIIehEDac") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const dsh = dss.getSheets()[0];
  const incl = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];//Sheetname to archive
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~incl.indexOf(sh.getName())).filter(e => e).forEach(sh => {
    let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  });
}
```

References:

- [ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks, it may be the way I'm describing it. 

I have one 'master sheet' that has multiple tabs within it. I am archiving off these tabs (I'm assuming you're calling these tabs sheets in your example above?) and currently it archives them into separate sheets i.e one tab per individual sheet. 

So I'm trying to archive off the tabs into one sheet, I'll give your example a whirl and see if that does the trick. I hope I explained that!

Thanks

Matt

Comment: The code I wrote archives the sheets with names included in `incl` all into the first sheet of the dss

Comment: Thats brilliant thankyou very much, managed to get it working. Thanks for your help and have a great weekend!

Comment: I realize that google uses the terms sheets and spreadsheets synonymously however in google apps script there is a Class Spreadsheets and a Class Sheets and they both methods some of which are not in both groups.  So using the term sheets in place of spreadsheets can be confusing here.